# How to update the state of a LazyColumn when List object's data is modifying in Compose?

Tags: android

Below is the composable, viewmodel and data class I have. I have lazyColumn which is is showing section List. In each section there is a separate question list. When I remove the question form the list, it is removed from the list but state is not updating.

```
@Composable
fun CreateQuestion(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: CreateQuestionViewModel,
    classId: String,
    className: String,
    subjectId: String,
    subjectName: String,
    mediumId: String,
    updatedSection: String?
) {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = updatedSection) {
        if (updatedSection != null) {

            val updatedSectionX = Gson().fromJson(updatedSection, Section::class.java)

            viewModel.sectionList.find { it.sectionId == viewModel.activeSection }?.questions =
                updatedSectionX?.questions
        }
    }

    Scaffold(topBar = {
        CustomTopAppBar(
            title = "Generate Exam Paper",
            showBack = true,
            onBackClick = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            },
            actionIcon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_print),
            onIconClick = {

                //Find of any question has null heading, if found we will return
                val heading = viewModel.sectionList.find { it.selectedHeading == null }

                //Find of any question has null marks, if found we will return
                val marks = viewModel.sectionList.find { it.marks.isNullOrEmpty() }

                //Find of any question has null questions, if found we will return
                val questions = viewModel.sectionList.find { it.questions.isNullOrEmpty() }

                if (heading != null) {
                    context.toast("Please add Heading")
                } else if (marks != null) {
                    context.toast("Please add Marks")
                } else if (questions != null) {
                    context.toast("Please add Questions")
                } else {



                    val paperDataStr = viewModel.prepareRequest(
                        classId = classId,
                        className = className,
                        subjectId = subjectId,
                        subjectName = subjectName,
                        mediumId = mediumId
                    )
                    navController.navigate(Screens.PrintSettings.withArgs(paperDataStr))
                }
            }
        )
    }, floatingActionButton = {
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            onClick = {
                val newSection = Section(
                    hasSectionName = viewModel.sectionWiseCheckedState.value,
                    sectionName = viewModel.getSectionName(),
                    headingList = viewModel.headingList,
                    selectedHeading = viewModel.headingList[0],
                    marks = ""
                )

                viewModel.sectionList.add(newSection)
                viewModel.sectionList.sortBy { it.sectionName[0].code }
                viewModel.lastSectionName.value = newSection.sectionName[0].code
            },
            containerColor = Blue,
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Add Question Title", style = TextStyle(
                    color = Color.White,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksand_medium))
                )
            )
        }
    }) { innerPadding ->

        val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            ScreenBackground()

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.getHeadingList(
                        classId = classId, subjectId = subjectId
                    )
                }
            }

            val getHeadingState by remember { viewModel.getHeadingState }.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
            when (getHeadingState) {
                is UiState.Empty -> {}
                is UiState.UnAuthorised -> {
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        val errorMessage = (getHeadingState as UiState.UnAuthorised).errorMessage
                        context.toast(message = errorMessage)
                        navController.navigate(Screens.LoginScreen.route) {
                            popUpToTop(navController)
                        }
                    }
                }

                is UiState.Error -> {
                    val errorMessage = (getHeadingState as UiState.Error).errorMessage
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        context.toast(message = errorMessage)
                    }
                }

                is UiState.Loading -> {
                    Loader()
                }

                is UiState.Success -> {

                    viewModel.headingList.clear()
                    viewModel.headingList =
                        (getHeadingState as UiState.Success).data.headingListData.headingList.toMutableList()

                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(
                            start = screenPadding(),
                            top = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding(),
                            end = screenPadding(),
                            bottom = screenPadding()
                        )
                    ) {

                        VerticalSpacer(size = 8)

                        QuestionPreferenceCheckBox(text = "Section wise paper?",
                            checkedState = viewModel.sectionWiseCheckedState.value,
                            onCheckedChange = {
                                viewModel.sectionWiseCheckedState.value = it
                            })

                        VerticalSpacer(size = 3)

                        if (viewModel.sectionWiseCheckedState.value) {
                            QuestionPreferenceCheckBox(text = "Add new question in same section?",
                                checkedState = viewModel.newQueSameSectionCheckedState.value,
                                onCheckedChange = {
                                    viewModel.newQueSameSectionCheckedState.value = it
                                })
                        }

                        VerticalSpacer(size = 25)


                        LazyColumn(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp), content = {

                            itemsIndexed(viewModel.sectionList) { index, section ->

                                var mExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                                var selectedHeading by remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.headingList[0]) }
                                var marks by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

                                Column(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .background(
                                            color = LightBlue,
                                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(5.dp))
                                        )
                                        .padding(8.dp)
                                ) {
                                    if (viewModel.sectionWiseCheckedState.value and section.hasSectionName) {
                                        Text(
                                            text = "Section ${section.sectionName}",
                                            style = TextStyle(
                                                color = Blue,
                                                fontSize = 13.sp,
                                                fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
                                                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksand_semi_bold))
                                            ),
                                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                                        )
                                    }

                                    Column(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .wrapContentHeight()
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                    ) {
                                        Text(
                                            text = "Question Title", style = TextStyle(
                                                color = TitleColor,
                                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                                fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
                                                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksand_semi_bold))
                                            )
                                        )

                                        VerticalSpacer(size = 5)
                                        QuestionTitleDropDown(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                            mExpanded = mExpanded,
                                            items = viewModel.headingList,
                                            selectedHeading = section.selectedHeading
                                                ?: selectedHeading,
                                            onClick = { mExpanded = mExpanded.not() },
                                            onDismissRequest = { mExpanded = false },
                                            onItemSelect = {
                                                selectedHeading = it
                                                mExpanded = false
                                                section.selectedHeading = it
                                            })

                                        VerticalSpacer(size = 8)

                                        Row(
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .wrapContentHeight()
                                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                                        ) {

                                            WhiteTextField(modifier = Modifier.width(70.dp),
                                                text = section.marks ?: marks,
                                                placeholderText = "Marks",
                                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
                                                imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
                                                onNext = {
                                                    localFocusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                                                },
                                                onValueChange = {
                                                    marks = it
                                                    viewModel.sectionList[index] =
                                                        section.copy(marks = it)
                                                })

                                            HorizontalSpacer(size = 10)

                                            if (!section.questions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                                                section.questions?.forEachIndexed { index1, questionData ->
                                                    Row(
                                                        modifier = Modifier
                                                            .width(100.dp)
                                                            .background(
                                                                color = AppLightGreen,
                                                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                                                            )
                                                    ) {
                                                        Text(
                                                            text = (index + 1).toString(),
                                                            style = TextStyle(
                                                                color = TitleColor,
                                                                fontSize = 14.sp
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                        IconButton(onClick = {

                                                            viewModel.removeQuestion(index, index1)

                                                            viewModel.removeQuestion(index, index1)

                                                            val tempSection = viewModel.sectionList[index].questions!!
                                                            tempSection.removeAt(index1)

                                                            viewModel.sectionList[index] = section.copy(
                                                                questions = tempSection
                                                            )
                                                        }) {
                                                            Icon(
                                                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_close),
                                                                contentDescription = "Delete Question"
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }


                                            HorizontalSpacer(size = 10)

                                            Row(
                                                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                                            ) {
                                                Box(
                                                    modifier = Modifier
                                                        .size(40.dp)
                                                        .background(
                                                            color = Blue,
                                                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                                                        ), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                                                ) {
                                                    IconButton(
                                                        onClick = {
                                                            coroutineScope.launch {

                                                                viewModel.activeSection =
                                                                    viewModel.sectionList[index].sectionId

                                                                val sectionStr =
                                                                    Gson().toJson(section)

                                                                Log.e("Paper 1", sectionStr)

                                                                navController.navigate(
                                                                    Screens.ChapterList.withArgs(
                                                                        sectionStr,
                                                                        classId,
                                                                        subjectId,
                                                                        subjectName
                                                                    )
                                                                )
                                                            }
                                                        }, modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)
                                                    ) {
                                                        Icon(
                                                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add,
                                                            contentDescription = null,
                                                            tint = Color.White
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                if (viewModel.sectionList.size > 1) {
                                                    HorizontalSpacer(size = 10)
                                                }

                                                if (viewModel.sectionList.size > 1) {

                                                    Box(
                                                        modifier = Modifier
                                                            .size(40.dp)
                                                            .background(
                                                                color = Blue,
                                                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                                                            ), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                                                    ) {
                                                        IconButton(
                                                            onClick = {

                                                                viewModel.deletedSections.add(
                                                                    section.sectionName[0].toInt()
                                                                )

                                                                viewModel.sectionList.remove(
                                                                    section
                                                                )
                                                            }, modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)
                                                        ) {
                                                            Icon(
                                                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Delete,
                                                                contentDescription = null,
                                                                tint = Color.White
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class CreateQuestionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository, private val prefManager: PreferencesManager
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _getHeadingState = MutableStateFlow<UiState<HeadingListResponse>>(UiState.Empty)
    val getHeadingState: StateFlow<UiState<HeadingListResponse>> get() = _getHeadingState

    val sectionWiseCheckedState = mutableStateOf(false)
    val newQueSameSectionCheckedState = mutableStateOf(false)
    val lastSectionName = mutableIntStateOf(65)
    var sectionList = mutableStateListOf<Section>()
    var headingList = mutableListOf<HeadingData>()
    val deletedSections = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var activeSection = 0

    fun removeQuestion(sectionIndex: Int, questionIndex: Int) {
        sectionList[sectionIndex].questions?.removeAt(questionIndex)
        sectionList[sectionIndex] = sectionList[sectionIndex]
    }

    init {
        val section = Section(
            hasSectionName = true,
            sectionName = lastSectionName.value.toChar().toString(),
            headingList = headingList,
            selectedHeading = null,
            marks = null
        )

        sectionList.add(section)
        activeSection = section.sectionId
    }

    fun prepareRequest(
        classId: String, className: String, subjectId: String, subjectName: String, mediumId: String
    ): String {

        val mainList = mutableListOf<DummyRequest>()

        sectionList.forEach {

            val qList = mutableListOf<QuestionsArr>()

            it.questions?.forEach { it2 ->
                val questionArr = QuestionsArr(
                    qId = it2.qId, question = it2.question, options = it2.options
                )

                qList.add(questionArr)
            }

            val dummyRequest = DummyRequest(
                isSectionName = it.hasSectionName,
                sectionName = it.sectionName,
                heading = it.selectedHeading?.headingName!!,
                marks = it.marks?.toInt()!!,
                questionsArr = qList
            )

            mainList.add(dummyRequest)

        }

        val paperData = PaperData(
            sectionList = sectionList,
            classId = classId,
            className = className,
            subjectId = subjectId,
            subjectName = subjectName,
            mediumId = mediumId
        )

//        val x = Json.encodeToString(paperData)

        val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<PaperData> = moshi.adapter(PaperData::class.java)
        val jsonString = adapter.toJson(paperData)
        val encodedJsonString = URLEncoder.encode(jsonString, "utf-8")

        //return Gson().toJson(x)
        return encodedJsonString
    }

    suspend fun getHeadingList(classId: String, subjectId: String) = viewModelScope.launch {

        val userId = prefManager.getUserId.first()!!
        val token = prefManager.getToken.first()!!

        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
        headers[Constants.TOKEN_KEY] = token

        val request = HeadingListRequest(
            deviceType = Constants.DEVICE_TYPE,
            userId = userId,
            classId = classId,
            subjectId = subjectId
        )

        try {
            val response = userRepository.getHeadingList(headerMap = headers, request = request)
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                sectionList[0].selectedHeading = response.headingListData.headingList[0]
                _getHeadingState.value = UiState.Success(response)
            } else {
                _getHeadingState.value = UiState.Error(response.message)
            }
        } catch (e: UnAuthorisedException) {
            prefManager.clearData()
            _getHeadingState.value = UiState.UnAuthorised(e.message)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            _getHeadingState.value = UiState.Error(e.message)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _getHeadingState.value = UiState.Error(e.message)
        }
    }

    fun getSectionName(): String {

        var sectionName = ""

        if (sectionWiseCheckedState.value and newQueSameSectionCheckedState.value.not()) {

            if (deletedSections.isNotEmpty()) {
                sectionName = (deletedSections.min()).toChar().toString()
                val isExist = sectionList.find { it.sectionName == sectionName }
                if (isExist != null) {
                    sectionName = (lastSectionName.value + 1).toChar().toString()
                }
            } else {
                sectionName = (sectionList.last().sectionName[0].code + 1).toChar().toString()
            }
        } else {
            sectionName = if (deletedSections.isNotEmpty()) {
                (deletedSections.min()).toChar().toString()
            } else {
                sectionList.last().sectionName
            }
        }

        return sectionName
    }
}
```

```
data class Section(
    var sectionId: Int = Random.nextInt(10000),
    var hasSectionName: Boolean,
    var sectionName: String,
    val headingList: List<HeadingData>,
    var selectedHeading: HeadingData?,
    var marks: String?,
    var questions: MutableList<QuestionData>? = null
)
```

On click of remove I am calling below code

```
viewModel.removeQuestion(index, index1)

val tempSection = viewModel.sectionList[index].questions!!

tempSection.removeAt(index1)

viewModel.sectionList[index] = section.copy(questions = tempSection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting your business logic into UI/Jetpack Compose is not good practice, so move your question-removing code into ViewModel. And here's some working example, I hope it might be helpful to fix your state's not reflected in the UI issue.

```
data class Section(
   val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
   val name: String,
   var questions: MutableList<Question>,
   var updatedAt: Long
)

data class Question(
  val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
  val title: String,
  val content: String
)
class ExampleVM : ViewModel() {

val sections = mutableStateListOf<Section>()

private fun generateData() {

    repeat(10) {

        val questions = mutableListOf<Question>()

        repeat(Random.nextInt(2, 5)) {
            questions.add(
                Question(title = "Question ${it}", content = "Content ${it}")
            )
        }

        sections.add(
            Section(
                name = "Section $it",
                questions = questions,
                updatedAt = System.currentTimeMillis()
            )
        )
    }
 }

init {
    generateData()
}

fun removeQuestion(section: Section, question: Question) {
    val sectionIndex = sections.indexOfFirst { it.id == section.id }
    val questions = sections[sectionIndex].questions
    questions.removeIf { it.id == question.id }
    sections[sectionIndex] = sections[sectionIndex].copy(
        questions = questions, updatedAt = System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
  }

@Composable
fun SectionList(
   sections: SnapshotStateList<Section>,
   onQuestionItemClick: (section: Section, question: Question) -> Unit
) {
     LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
       items(sections) {
          SectionItem(
             Modifier
                 .fillMaxWidth(),
             section = it
          ) { question ->
            onQuestionItemClick(it, question)
            }
       }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SectionItem(
   modifier: Modifier,
   section: Section, onQuestionItemClick: (question: Question) -> Unit = 
   {}
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {

       Text(text = section.name)

       QuestionList(
         questions = section.questions.toList(),
         onQuestionItemClick = onQuestionItemClick
       )
    }
 }

@Composable
fun QuestionList(
  questions: List<Question>,
  onQuestionItemClick: (question: Question) -> Unit = {}
) {
   Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
      repeat(questions.size) {
         val question = questions[it]
         Text(text = question.title, modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable { onQuestionItemClick.invoke(question) })
      }
   }
 }
```